# Have the class as value in a dictionary

Tags: python, class, dictionary

I have a class:

```
class Competition:

    def __init__(self, year = int, distance = int, stages = int, winner = None , cyclist = list):
        self.year = year
        self.distance = distance
        self.stages = stages
        self.winner = winner
        self.cyclist = cyclist


    def __str__(self):
        return "Competition({}, {}, {}, {}, {}".format(self.year, self.distance, self.stages, self.winner, self.cyclist)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "{} {} {} {} {}".format(self.year, self.distance, self.stages, self.winner, self.cyclist)
```

And I want to add the class to a dictionary as the value, and as key the years.
The information I get is from a file.

So I have this

```
 with open('tour-de-france.csv') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    no_header = next(reader, None)

    new_dict = {}
    for x in reader:
        new_dict[int(x[0])] = Competition(int(x[0]), x[3], x[11], None,[])
    print(new_dict)
```

Part of the output is:

```
{1903: 1903 2428 6 None [], 1904: 1904 2428 6 None [], 1905: 1905 2994 11 None [],
```

But I would like it as:

```
{1903: Competition(1903, 2428, 6, None, []), 1904: Competition(1904, 2428, 6, None, []), 1905: Competition(1905, 2994, 11, None, []),
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When printing dictionaries with classes in them, it will print the return value of the `__repr__` function. Therefore, you can simply make the `__repr__` function as follows (since the `__str__` function is already returning the value that you want):

```
def __repr__(self):
    return self.__str__()
```

Comment: Yea, that's it! Thanks for pointing out. I made the repr before I did the dictionary, I forgot about that. Again thanks for pointing out!

Comment: You can also just do `__repr__ = __str__` in the class definition after `def __str__(self):`.

Answer (score 2):

As @Seth Peace said, the thing is that in order to get a string value for your class, Python calls `__repr__` if it is defined, not `__str__`.

However, a cleaner way to do this can be to use a dataclass:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Optional

@dataclass
class Competition:
    year: int
    distance: int
    stages: int
    winner: Optional[str]
    cyclist: list

print(Competition(2019, 3, 5, "John Doe", []))
```

By doing so, `__init__`, `__str__` and `__repr__` will already have been defined in a meaningful way.

Answer (score 0):

When you print a container, it includes the repr of its elements. The problem is that you've swapped the `__str__` and `__repr__` methods.

Although, there's not much point in having a separate `__str__` if it's practically the same as `__repr__` just written a bit different. I would add some additional info to make it more helpful to an end user.

As well, you've mixed up type annotations and default values in `__init__`. All the ones that have a type as their default value are incorrect. Only `winner` is correct, but because it has a default and the others don't, it needs to go at the end.

```
class Competition:

    def __init__(self, year: int, distance: int, stages: int, cyclist: list, winner=None):
        self.year = year
        self.distance = distance
        self.stages = stages
        self.cyclist = cyclist
        self.winner = winner

    def __repr__(self):
        s = "Competition({}, {}, {}, {}, {})".format(
            self.year,
            self.distance,
            self.stages,
            self.cyclist,
            self.winner
            )
        return s

    def __str__(self):
        s = "{}: {} km, {} stages, winner {} out of {})".format(
            self.year,
            self.distance,
            self.stages,
            self.winner,
            self.cyclist,
            )
        return s
```

(You were also missing a closing parenthesis inside the format string.)

And then instantiation would look like this:

```
year = int(x[0])
new_dict[year] = Competition(year, x[3], x[11], [])
```

For example:

```
c = Competition(1903, 2428, 6, [])
print(c)  # -> 1903: 2428 km, 6 stages, winner None out of [])
print(repr(c))  # -> Competition(1903, 2428, 6, [], None)
```

Answer (score -1):

You cannot have the *class* as a value in this way. You sure can pass a reference to the class itself, but having it this way (`Competition(1903, 2428, 6, None, [])`) what you actually want is to print an object - an [instance to a class](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#classes). So, if you want to print a string that is like the desired output you should do something like you already did with `__str__`, but it will be a string (enclosed in quotes) instead of the declarative class form.

Comment: No, OP can use `__repr__` to get the representation they want, not enclosed in quotes. As well, the distinction between a class and instance in this case is pedantic - we all understood what OP meant.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @wjandrea, wasn't completely aware of this fact for `__repr__`. As for being pedantic about objects vs. instances it was definitely not the intention, it's just because I've seen so many code errors coming from people not actually getting the difference between those two that I try to explain this every time I can :)

Comment: Oh, I see. Yes, that's good to point out :) But IMO it would be better to phrase it as an aside rather than as "No, you can't do that".